# No event getting generated on button click in MFC

Tags: button, mfc, onclick

I have a dialog based application. I have one static text control and a button on this, both of which I have made invisible in the beginning. I want to show both the controls on reaching a certain condition. When I click this button, again I want to make both the controls invisible.
However, I am able to show and hide the control and also captured the button click event like this:

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MY_BUTTON, &MyDlg::OnBnClickedMyButton)
```

and defined OnBnClickedMyButton().
But when I press the button, it is not pressed and the event is also not generated.
Any suggestions?

Comment: once check button id, double click the button and check you are getting OnBnClickedMyButton(); or not.

Comment: Use Spy++ to 'spy' the button down message to determine what code is responding to it.

Answer (score 1):

- First check if the `IDC_MY_BUTTON` exists and is valid.
- Remember to add `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()` at the header file.
- Also check at the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyClass,MyParentClass)` if the class
  and the parent class you write are right.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `IDC_MY_BUTTON` maybe is invalid or other control has the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I have come to know that though the button was visible but on clicking it was not taking control, hence I used `BringWindowToTop()` to draw it on top. Now it is being clicked and `OnBnClickedMyButton()` is also being called.

But now the issue is that after calling `BringWindowToTop()` the button is not shown. It is shown only when I take the mouse pointer on it. Not able to understand what is the issue.